# How to render item when data is updated react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hi guys I am currently facing a problem where in I need to update the data inside of a pop up

here's my code

```
useEffect(() => {
    return ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const list = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const {
                accepted,id,name,rating,services,userDestinationLat,userDestinationLng,userOriginLat,userOriginLng
            } = doc.data();
            list.push({ accepted, id, name, rating, services, userDestinationLat, userDestinationLng, userOriginLat, userOriginLng });
        });
        setUserBookingData(list);
    });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    // use this just to get userbookingData
    console.log(userBookingData);

},[userBookingData]);

const [newOrder, setNewOrder] = useState({ 
    id: '1',
    service: userBookingData.services,
    originLatitude : originalPos.latitude,
    originLongitude: originalPos.longitude,
    destinationLatitude: 45.24953,
    destinationLongitude: -76.360733,
    user:{
        rating: userBookingData.rating,
        name: userBookingData.name,
    }
});
```

now here on my return view

```
return(
 { !userBookingData.length ? (<NewOrderPopUp  
                newOrder={newOrder}
                onDecline={onDecline}
                duration={2}
                distance={0.5}
                onAccept={() => onAccept(newOrder)}
                />) : (
                    <View></View>
                ) 
            }
);
```

here's the popup component it's in another page

```
const NewOrderPopUp = ({newOrder, onAccept, onDecline, duration, distance}) => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.root}>

            <Pressable onPress={onDecline} style={styles.declineButton}>
                <Text style={styles.declineText}>Decline</Text>
            </Pressable>

            <Pressable onPress={onAccept} style={styles.popupContainer}>
                
                <View style = {styles.row}>
                    <Text style = {styles.service}>{newOrder.service}</Text>
                    {/* <Image source={{}}/> */}
                    <View style={styles.userBg}>
                        <FontAwesome name={"user"} color={"white"} size={35}/>
                    </View>
                    <Text style = {styles.service}>
                        <AntDesign name={"star"}  size={16}/>
                        {newOrder.user.rating}
                    </Text>
                </View>

                <Text style = {styles.minutes}>{duration} mins</Text>
                <Text style = {styles.distance}>{distance} KM</Text>
                
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    );
};
```

it won't update the data / show the pop up wen there's a data

The expectation output is it should be able to pop up the `NewOrderPopUp` screen when there's a data.

here's the data from the `userBookingData`

[image]

I need to display it here

[image]

Comment: what new data are you expecting it to show? and where is the `NewOrderPopUp` component?

Comment: @RedBaron see edit for more information sir

Comment: I think you need to add dependencies into your first useEffect. so that it re-triggers when something changes, updates your state, which updates your props, which re-renders your component

Comment: the second useEffect has already the userBookingData and can be displayed using console. The problem I am currently facing is that the `NewPopUpOrder` screen doesn't update its value

Comment: the second useEffect is not doing anything though. it's just console.logging the value? are you saying you are not seeing any updates in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are filling `userBookingData` in first `useEffect` does not allow you to write an `useState` getting value from `userBookingData` itself.

React doesn't work like that.

Not only but if I understand correctly, `userBookingData` is an array so write `userBookingData.services` returns `null`.

Lets suppose that you want to have in `newOrder` the first element that comes from `userBookingData`. In this case, you should write something like:

```
const [newOrder, setNewOrder] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    return ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const list = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const {
                accepted,id,name,rating,services,userDestinationLat,userDestinationLng,userOriginLat,userOriginLng
            } = doc.data();
            list.push({ accepted, id, name, rating, services, userDestinationLat, userDestinationLng, userOriginLat, userOriginLng });
        });
        setUserBookingData(list);
        // here set newOrder
        let resultObj = {};
        resultObj.id = 1;
        resultObj.service = list[0].services;
        ...
        setNewOrder(resultObj);
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: I was blinded because of the console.log data . I'm very sorry and thank you for the explaination good sir .

Comment: @Ginxxx no problem. Have a nice coding =)